Getting precise geolocation and not the wifi geolocation
In my current react project, I want to have the app do something different depending on the location on campus.
Thing is, we could assume some people will be connected to the wifi. And when connected to the campus wifi, anywhere you are, the coordinates are the same. The IT department office.
Is there a way to bypass the via the current internet connexion geolocation and get the device's geolocation (if there is one, which I would assume most recent devices will)
Or will I have to put a warning if the coordinates that come up are the IT office tell users to get off the wifi?
Currently using the react-geolocated package, but i'm not far into the weeds, could change if another package would permit it.
